# spring 2.5 jstl view error

Tags: java, spring, frameworks

I have the following controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/project/view.html")
public class ProjectViewController {

 private static final String viewName = "projectView";


 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showPage(Model model,
   @RequestParam(value="id",required=false) Long id) {

  //code.....

  return viewName;
 }

}
```

My views.properties contains

```
projectView.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
projectView.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/project/view.jsp
```

Everything works as expected.

But I needed to change the method to return a View(), cause I have to return a RedirectView() to some error page if something fails. So I've changed the method to:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/project/view.html")
public class ProjectViewController {

 private static final String viewName = "projectView";


 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public View showPage(Model model,
   @RequestParam(value="id",required=false) Long id) {

  //code.....

  return new JstlView(viewName);
 }

}
```

But in this case I get a NPE :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.getServletContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:121)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.exposeHelpers(JstlView.java:133)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:257)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1183)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:902)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
 at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I've debugged and it seems that getWebApplicationContext() returns null.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: it works if I change the method to return a ModelAndView() instead of just a View()

Comment: What version of Spring is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of your exception is that instances of `JstlView` need to be injected with certain things before they can be used, for example the current `WebApplicationContext`. Normally, this is transparent to you, because Spring instantiates and prepares `JstlView` for you. It's only when you do it yourself, that you see what's involved.

Now, you *could* call `setApplicationContext` on the `JstlView` that you instantiate, but you don't want your controllers getting involved in that sort of thing. You really want to keep Spring doing the work.

Now, since you're using `views.properties`, it follows that you're also using `ResourceBundleViewResolver` to resolve your views. The trick here is to realise that Spring can handle *multiple* view resolvers in the same context, it'll simply ask them one after the other, until one of them resolves the view name.

So my suggestion would be to add another resolver to your context, this time an `InternalResourceViewResolver` (this is actually the default resolver, but that default is suppressed when you specified your `ResourceBundleViewResolver`).

Now, when you return a view name that the `ResourceBundleViewResolver` can't resolve, the `InternalResourceViewResolver` will be consulted.

`InternalResourceViewResolver` just takes the view name as the actual JSP path (e.g. return `/WEB-INF/page.jsp` directly from your controller method). It also lets you use syntax like `redirect:/path/to/my/url`.

So yours other controllers can keep on returning view names as specified in `views.properties`, but now in addition you can return dynamically-assembled `redirect:x/y/` view names, which will be translated by `InternalResourceViewResolver` into a `RedirectView`. No need to construct these views yourself.

One last point to note: the view resolvers are consulted in the order in which they appear in the beans file, and `InternalResourceViewResolver` *must* come last in that list.

Answer (score 3):

`JstlView` implements `ApplicationContextAware` and `ServletContextAware`, so you should call `setApplicationContext` and `setServletContext` (and, probably, some other initializations) if you want to instantiate it manually.

But you can define a `RedirectView` in your `views.properties`, so you don't have to return a `View` object yourself:

```
someRedirectView.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
someRedirectView.url=/redirectHere
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like an elegant solution to define redirect views in views.properties. 

But what if I need to build the redirect url at request time, something like "/redirectHere?id=" + id; Is it still possible to define it somehow in views.properties, and parameterize it?

Comment: By default RedirectView exposes model attributes as URL parameters, so you can add your id to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work

```
> projectView.url=redirect:/WEB-INF/jsp/project/view.jsp
```